# PayPal Mobile SDK, payment to other merchant account

Tags: mobile, paypal

Both Mobile Express Checkout and Adaptive Payments allow me to specify account for money receiving explicitly. I just need to set PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID for Express Checkout or receiverList.receiver(0).email for Adaptive Payments.

Is there same functionality for PayPal Mobile SDK? Looks like I can only create payment to my account (linked to client_id in PayPalConfiguration), not to other merchants accounts. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here. You are correct: at this moment, the PayPal Mobile SDK does not allow you to choose at runtime the merchant who will be paid. We do expect that in the coming months this ability will be added to the PayPal REST APIs on which the Mobile SDK relies; when that happens, we'll definitely add this functionality to the SDK.